# SKPhysicsJointPin iOS How to create swinging motion

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have 2 physics bodies. One is a flying bird and the other is a basket that i want should be hanging from the birds mouth. I am creating an SKPhysicsJointPin to create this effect. It is not working correctly. The bird physics body has following parameters

```
-(void) setupPhysicsBody{
enemyBird.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];

enemyBird.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
enemyBird.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
enemyBird.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = TECollisionCategoryEnemyBird; 

enemyBird.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0; 
enemyBird.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = TECollisionCategoryMissile;
```

}

The basket physics body has following parameters

```
basket.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
basket.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
basket.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = TECollisionCategoryBasket;
```

Now inside the scene i am creating the joint

```
TEBasketNode *basket = [TEBasketNode basketAtPoint:CGPointMake(enemyBird.position.x - enemyBird.frame.size.width/2,
                                                                   enemyBird.position.y - 20)];

    [self addChild:basket];

    SKPhysicsJointPin *pinJoint = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:enemyBird.physicsBody
                                                              bodyB:basket.physicsBody anchor:enemyBird.position];
    pinJoint.shouldEnableLimits = YES;
    pinJoint.lowerAngleLimit = -0.35;
    pinJoint.upperAngleLimit = 0.35;
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:pinJoint];
```

There is some odd behaviour here. The bird is flying and the basket just swings from left side to the right once and then remains like that. It swings just one side and doesn't swing back with respect to its anchor point. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you set the shouldEnableLimits property to NO? Your limits are set to -20 to 20 degrees, and 0 degrees is pointing to the right.

Comment: If i set to to NO, the basket moves to the right all the way to the right and it rotates completely till it touches the bird itself. It doesn't come back.

Comment: Does the basket swing to the right due to the movement of the bird? If so you will need a force, for example gravity, to make it swing back.

Comment: It appears i had incorrect anchor point. If i adjust anchor point to the exact point of the birds mouth and set shouldEnableLimits to YES or NO.. both ways the basket doesn't rotate at all. Any ideas how to make it swing to and fro?

Comment: Try setting the basket.physicsBody's affectedByGravity property to YES and set its collisionBitMask to 0.

Comment: no, it goes right to the bottom along with the bird.. doesn't work

Comment: Gravity is pulling the bird and the basket downward. For testing purposes try setting the dynamic property of the bird's physicsBody to NO. You can then focus on getting the basket to swing correctly.

Comment: Have you already tried playing with the `lowerAngleLimit` and `upperAngleLimit`? Try expanding the range and see if that has an effect.